# Script to generate gallery from current directory

Tags: images, php, webserver

I'm searching for a small script (.php) that will generate a gallery from the current directory. I hope you know what I mean. Something like below. **EDIT**: I mean something that requires no installation, no configuration, etc. I need just put this script in the directory with images, open in web-browser and get simple gallery.

`/var/www/some/directory:`

```
a.jpg
b.jpg
c.jpg
d.jpg
gallery_script.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something :) [Single File PHP Gallery](http://sye.dk/sfpg/). Demo [here](http://sye.dk/sfpg/demo/).

Answer (score 1):

[PhpGraphy](http://phpgraphy.sourceforge.net/) should do the job.

If you do not want any installation try this:

```
<?php 
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        $ext = end(explode('.', $file));
        if($ext == "jpg" || $ext == "png") {
            echo "<img src=\"$file\" alt=\"Image\" />";
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: I was thinking of something simpler, no installation, no configuration  etc. Just put in a directory and get image gallery.

Answer (score 1):

A Very Simple PHP file that searches the current directory for jpg, png and gif files and puts it in a HTML `<img>` tag.

```
<?php
$format = '<img src="[FILE]"> [FILE]<br>';

chdir(dirname(__FILE__));

$files = glob("*.{jpeg,jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);

foreach ($files as $file) {
    if (is_file($file)) {
        echo str_replace('[FILE]', htmlspecialchars($file), $format);
    }
}
?>
```

Nothing fancy, it shows all images after each other. Save it as `index.php`. Your webserver should support PHP and usually shows `index.php` for directories.

Answer (score 0):

[TStarGallery](http://tstargallery-php-gallery-script.downloadaces.com/) seems to be exactly what you want. If you want something a little more configurable, something like [Gallery](http://gallery.menalto.com/) would require a bit more work to set up, but reward you with more options.

Comment: I can not download `TStarGallery`. http://tstar.taillandier.de/tstargallery/tstargallery10.rar = 403 Forbidden